# How to return late response from api - node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I am making request to an api, and they(API owners) mentioned that their response can be immediate and also can be delayed sometimes like sometimes it will be 2 hours but I have to do action on basis of that response. What process should I go with? should I use timers, cron jobs or any better way you can suggest.

```
//axios,other stuff
const getUsersList = async (req, res) => {
  axios
    .get("https://thirdparty.com/api/some_url/" + req.params.email)
    .then((res) => {
      //this action i want to perform on response but it comes after two hours mostly
      await User.create({
        firstName: res.data.first_name,
      });
    });

  res.status({ message: "your details are saved" });
};
```

I can't make someone wait for two hours as it will be bad User experience, so what is the procedure to go with?

Comment: "2 hours"? that doesn't sound like something you'd want to use `axios` for

Comment: it's like list of users that i get on basis of email i send
how else am i supposed to make call then?

Comment: Why cant you use socket connection?

Comment: the API owners would be able to explain how to use the API they own - if "they" made an API with a 2 hour delay in response, then there is nothing you can do, since you are using their API

Comment: what will we the procedure with it? I actually what should be the procedure to with in my question. I mean it would be nice if you suggest a road map

Comment: a road map? I think you're throwing random terms in hoping they mean something

Comment: yes #Reyno that is why i am here as  I can't make anyone wait for response

Comment: so, you want a timeout - axios will timeout, and you use a `.catch` to handle it, like you would with any error

Comment: "timers" ... suggests you want to not wait 2 hours for a response ... sorry if I can't interpret your question better - since your code is invalid anyway, it doesn't help explain what you want at all

Comment: Kindly, read the description. I am trying to explain that I am getting response from an api whose response time is from 1min to  2 hours, so i dont want to wait two hours
so is there anyways that the response i get after two hours i can store it at any place
I am basically asking about how to know  that i have got the response as firsty it will not even wait because of timeout

Comment: Just ask your api provider , if they have any webhook or something for that, then you can listen to that webhook, else no other option , you need support from that API provider, or read API doc again for any WebSocket / Webhook methods mentioned there

Comment: ok i will ask about webhooks